# Odoo 10 - Form view opened in edit mode

Tags: odoo, odoo-view

I'm developing on Odoo 10.

I created a dynamic form view which search and display a product from its barcode, but I've got a problem.

Since the view has no initial record to display it is opened in edit mode, and that's ok, because I want to type the *'barcode'* field.
But, after the product is displayed, when I exit from that view the *'can_be_discarded'* function is fired, opening the confirm dialog.

Have I to create a new view type inheriting from FormView or is there a way to workaround this problem?

---

The view is a classic form view, with nothing special.
Here's the server code instead.

```py
class ProductFromBarcode(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'levelprime_product_general_status.product_from_barcode'
    _inherits = { 'product.product': 'product_id' }

    product_id      = fields.Many2one(
                            comodel_name='product.product',
                            store=False)
    product_barcode = fields.Integer(help='Insert the barcode to search '
                                          'the correspondent product',
                                     store=False)

    @api.onchange('product_barcode')
    def on_barcode_changed(self):
        if self.product_barcode != 0:
            self.product_id = self.get_product_from_barcode(self.product_barcode)

    @api.model
    def get_product_from_barcode(self, barcode):
        r = self.env['product.product'].search([('barcode', '=', barcode)])
        if r:
            return r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I'm in the right way, there are some rendering problem to solve, but the main behavior is what I was searching for.

I created a new type of view which inherit from the *'FormView'* one and override the *'can_be_discarded'* method to not execute controls about the data changes.

---

JS

```
odoo.define('levelprime_product_general_status.readonly_formview', function(require) {
    'use strict'

    var core = require('web.core')
    var FormView = require('web.FormView')

    var ReadOnly_FormView = FormView.extend({
        init: function() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        },
        start: function() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        },
        can_be_discarded: function() {
            return $.Deferred().resolve()
        }
    })

    core.view_registry.add('readonly_form', ReadOnly_FormView)

    return ReadOnly_FormView
})
```

---

PY

```
class ViewExtension(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.ui.view'

    type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[
        ('readonly_form', 'ReadOnly Form Version')])
```

---

Then you can simply use the  tag in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have used  **_inherits = { 'product.product': 'product_id' }** in your wizard.

When using **_inherits** you will do a kind of polymorphic model in the database way.

For example **product.product inherits product.template** or **res.users inherits res.partner**.

This mean we create a model that gets the know how of a Model but adds aditional data/columns in a new database table. So when you create a user, all partner data is stored in **res_partner** table (and a partner is created) and all user related info is stored in **res_users** table.

In your code when wizard (**levelprime_product_general_status.product_from_barcode**) record will create then all **product.product/product.template** fields are required,due to that reason you are getting this type of error.

You can check difference between _inherit & _inherits from following link.

https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/the-different-openerp-model-inheritance-mechanisms-what-s-the-difference-between-them-and-when-should-they-be-used-46

You need to follow following code.

```
class ProductFromBarcode(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'levelprime_product_general_status.product_from_barcode'

    product_id= fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.product',string="Product")
    product_barcode = fields.Char(help='Insert the barcode to search '
                                          'the correspondent product',
                                     "Barcode")

    @api.onchange('product_barcode')
    def on_barcode_changed(self):
        if self.product_barcode:
            self.product_id = self.get_product_from_barcode(self.product_barcode)

    @api.model
    def get_product_from_barcode(self,barcode):
        r = self.env['product.product'].search([('barcode', '=', barcode)])
        if r:
            return r
        else:
            return False
```

In above code just create wizard & add two fields.
This may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man.   
But with this implementation I can't use *'product.product'* fields in the view to display. That's why I used the *'inherits'*.  
I tried to nest them inside the relation field but it only display me the *'product_id'*. Is there another way to display them without the *'inherits'*?

Comment: About code will work.You can replace this code, restart server & upgrade module. If you get any error then give me error log in detail..

Comment: If I nest the fields inside the relation one it gives me no errors, but it show only that single field. Otherwise it tells me that the fields of *'product.product'* do not exist.

Comment: In above code we have create one wizard in which there are two fields, you need to create view of wizard and add 2 fields inside wizard.system will show you both fields in the view.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, those fields are shown, but it's not what i would do. I would show various fields of the product related to the inserted barcode and I can't put them in the view, while with the inherits I can.

It's ok for me to create another table with the product data inside. The issue is that I would not save the record on that table. I would have a temporary record needed only to show the data in the view.

Comment: There are only two possibilities, if fields are less  required then you create in wizard  and set via on-change method or just visible product_id you can open form view directly from product_id.

Answer (score 0):

from what you are saying you are using inherits to show the information of the product selected by the barcode remove it and use related field:
add the fields that you are showing on the form view to you model

```
name = fields.Char(related='product_id.name', readonly=True)
```

Now you can use name on your view it's like compute field or proxy.
you can make them readonly if you want to display them.

Comment: That's a good solution. But I still got an issue. 
I would like to not display the confirm dialog of *'discard_changes'* while changing barcode and the other data consequently.
I'm afraid I have to override some *'FormView'* methods to skip that step to achieve that.